# magento google sitemap

Tags: magento-1.8, sitemaps, category-products

I generated a sitemap from magento admin panel -

```
caralog -> google sitemap
```

There are many links in my site which are not included, like

```
http://www.website.com/wishlist/
http://www.website.com/contactscutom/index
http://www.website.com/mysite-faq#refer
```

It seems only the links ending with `.html` are generated in sitemap.xml file, because all links in sitemap.xml are ending with `.html`.

Also the product sitemap only have url links which are `enabled` and whose visibility is `Catalog, search`. These filter are present in `/app/code/core/Mage/Sitemap/Model/Resource/Catalog/Product.php` file on line numbers 164 and 165 :

```
        $this->_addFilter($storeId, 'visibility', Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->getVisibleInSiteIds(), 'in');
        $this->_addFilter($storeId, 'status', Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->getVisibleStatusIds(), 'in');
```

I would like to know is this is the way sitemaps are generated? or should it include all the URL's present in magento website, including all products.

Answer (score 3):

This is the way the default Magento sitemap generates.

There are 3rd party extensions that will allow you to put all your pages in the sitemap, but by default, Magento doesn't like all of them.